# Xamarin, Android BottomNavigationBar 3rd-party library goes down in special situation

Tags: xamarin.android, xamarin.forms, bottomnavigationview

I used [this link](https://asyncawait.wordpress.com/2016/06/16/bottom-menu-for-xamarin-forms-android/) to implement BottomNavigationBar in xamarin forms, I need to have the BottomNavigationBar in all of my pages, in this case I have a problem:

1. If I define MainPage in App as a non-NavigationPage, and all inner pages as NavigationPage, the bottomNavigation goes down and only it’s icons are visible!
   ([image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PazWD.jpg), [image2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qyvBA.jpg))
2. If I define MainPage in App as a NavigationPage, and all inner pages as non-NavigationPage I'll not be able to see bottomNavigation in inner pages!
   ([image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ye6rj.jpg), [image2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l6PST.jpg))
3. If I define both MainPage and inner pages as NavigationPage, I will have two toolbars in inner pages.

I prefer the first option if it's possible, but I cannot handle that!

Answer (score 0):

Since you want your tabs to be visible all the time I would put your MainPage as a Tabbed page and then use NavigationPages as the tabs. This will allow you to have navigation in the tabs. You then place all your content in ContentPages, don't place your xaml in NavigationPages.

Navigation Pages, TabbedPages and MasterDetailsPages should contain only ContentPages.

You can find a sample in the Xamarin website: https://developer.xamarin.com/samples/xamarin-forms/Navigation/TabbedPageWithNavigationPage/